# How to overwrite other CSS files with BEM?

Tags: css, bem

I'm theming a project which has a base CSS file. I am meant to style the site using BEM, but am having trouble with this base file (which I cannot edit).

For example, there is a CTA a tag in the main-menu element, whose font-size I have styled as:

```
.main-menu {
  &__cta {
    font-size: .875rem;
  }
}
```

But this is overwritten by the base.css:

```
.main-menu a {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

I can make a selector like `.main-menu .cta {` but this breaks my BEM. I can also use `!important;` but this feels wrong.

Is there any 'BEM way' of getting around this problem?

PS, HTML for this example would be:

```
<div class="main-menu">
  <!--menu items-->
  <a class="main-menu__cta">Call-to-action</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just use `.main-menu__cta` as your CSS selector?

Comment: @Ouroborus yeah I am - that's what `.main-menu {  &__cta {` is

Comment: The problem is you need to overcome the more specific, existing selector, you want your end selector to look something like `.main-menu .main-menu__cta`. How is your understanding of CSS specificity?

Comment: @JonP This is true and I think might be the only way round this. It would just make my SASS clumsy is all.

Comment: The problem, is you are being forced to mix BEM, which is designed to have flat specificity, with a style sheet that is dependent on specificity. Oh and don't use `!important` or the CSS ogre will track you down and make you use tables for layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a double ampersand to increase the specificity, like this:

```
.main-menu {
    & &__cta {
        font-size: .875rem;
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c680f4hb/)

Answer (score 0):

The key to this is specificity, try something like below or even including a class or element outside of the snippet you've shown us to make your style more specific to your target.

```
div.main-menu {

    &__cta {

        font-size: .875rem;

    }

}
```